# Call powershell script from another

Tags: xml, powershell

I have 2 powershell scripts one processes low level xmfiles, the other reads in a top level xml file, pulls out ID values from it and then tries to call the low level xml file processing script, passing in the ID.
I developed the low level file first using a hard coded ID and it all now works fine.
I added param($ID) at the very top of the called file.
I then tried to call the file from the parent xml script thus:

./ChildXmlFile.ps1 "xyz"

This gives me an error:

./ChildXmlFile.ps1 is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I tried forward slash, back slash, with and without '.ps1' on the end, same result every time.

Is there a way of calling the script from the parent?  They both reside in the same directory on disk.  My working directory if you like.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dot source a script like this:

```
. .\ChildXmlFile.ps1 "xyz"
```

Comment: This kind of works but I had to specify the full path to the sub script file as Mike Wise alluded to but I didnt really know what he was was suggesting to do.
Thanks all

Comment: Thought I would put you over :)

Answer (score 0):

Powershell scripts don't inherit the directories of their parents when they are called for some reason - not doubt a security "feature". They start in the home directory of the user. I ran into this a couple of weeks ago and fixed it by passing the directory as an argument and doing a "cd" to that directory. I know this is a terrible hack, still looking for a good way to do it.